# Algorithm for probability over 100%

Tags: java, algorithm, language-agnostic, probability

I am in need of an algorithm (in Java, but the theory should be pretty general) for some sort of probability... thing. I don't even know what to call it, which is why I haven't had any luck Googling.

To describe a bit better, I have a task that needs to be done X number of times when a function is called. Sometimes, there's only a 1 in 10 chance of that happening, meaning that (approximately) one out of every ten times that function is called that task will actually be performed - easy enough to do with random(). Sometimes it will be 2 in 10, or maybe even 10 in 10. Still easy enough, straightforward conditional, even if it's not always "X in 10"

The problem is, it can have *greater* than a 1 in 1 chance. It may be 15 in 10 - half the time it runs once, the rest it runs *twice*. Or 10 in 5, where it runs twice (approximately) every time called. As you can see, this has now ventured out of simple inequality testing.

So, what I'm looking for is some algorithm that, based on random numbers, will return a run *count* based on how frequently (1 in 10, 200%, 0.75, whatever format works) something ought to happen. If anyone can provide any leads on this - like, maybe an actual term to search for - it'd be much appreciated!

EDIT: No wonder I can't find many results, everyone's as confused as I am!

First and foremost, no real "maximum" value. Not formally defined. If the algorithm can extract that from the probability value it receives, that's great.

It also definitely needs to be random, making it inherently imperfect. If you flip a coin 10 times, you may very well end up with 8 heads, even though it theoretically ought to be perfectly even! And that's alright. In fact, it's the point.

I could tell you *why* I need it... but that would be in violation of proper object-oriented modularity practices :) External parties need only know the interface; it accepts a value (probably a float, "0.75" seems like it would work best) and returns an int. If you call it 100 times, with a probability of 1 in 5, the sum of its returned values should average out to 20.

Comment: One of us doesn't get probabilities.

Comment: First, answer this: Why?

Comment: `while (likelihood > 10) { likelihood -= 10; routine.run(); }` then do your regular equality test.

Comment: You need to define maximum number of occurences somehow. If your default is 10 and you have 150%, multiply 10 times 150% and you get 15. I think I know what you are trying to do. You still need to do some rounding to do this 'hack'.

Comment: @dystroy Well, one of us got 110% in the college class that taught it :)

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'expected value'.

Comment: is this a situation where you 'reroll the dice' on any successful roll?  So if you have a 10% chance of performing the action; on each successful roll, you reroll, having a second 10% chance to do it a second time on that iteration?  That method could yield a higher number of actions than iterations if your probability is high enough or you give it enough turns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of executions for a given probability X is to be limited to `floor(X)` and `ceil(X)` (and never `floor(X)-1` or less or `ceil(X)+1` or more): (so 1.5 is 50% 1 and 50% 2 and 0.7 is 70% 1 and 30% 0)

```
int runCount = (int)probability;
if (randomGen.nextDouble() < probability - runCount)
  runCount++;
```

**EDIT:** Condensed as per DigitalMan's suggestion.

**EDIT 2:** Admittedly, this solution focusses on the "15 in 10 - half the time it runs once, the rest it runs twice" in the question and can be thought of as replacing the "approximately" in "10 in 5, where it runs twice (approximately) every time called" in the question with "exactly". The constraints are somewhat unclear.

Comment: This worked perfectly, runs fast, is straightforward, and can even be condensed: `int runs=(int)prob; if(Math.random() < (prob-runs)) {++runs;}`

Comment: This doesn't contradict anything stated in the question, but if `probability == 1` then this returns a steady rate of exactly 1 event every time. If that's not desirable, then the question needs more detail what "definitely needs to be random" should mean -- *how much* variation is needed?

Comment: @SteveJessop In a classic interpretation of probability, `1` indicates that an event will always happen. The question ("15 in 10 - half the time it runs once, the rest it runs twice") loosely implies that the run counts should be limited to `floor(X)` and `ceil(X)`, and naturally extends to say that a probability of `X` must always be executed exactly `X` times (at least from where I'm standing, I suppose it is open to interpretation).

Comment: @Dukeling: sure, but what I'm worried about is the "approximately" in "Or 10 in 5, where it runs twice (approximately) every time called". Exactly 2 is approximately 2, but perhaps there's a desire for it to be non-exact. I'm just not sure that the questioner has clear requirements yet, there are examples given but (as I read it) they aren't *necessarily* definitive or entirely coherent. +1, though, if "half the time it runs once, the rest it runs twice" is the requirement then of course you've hit it.

Comment: @Steve That "approximately" was added to preemptively stop people from whining that random numbers are unreliable or whatever, since "99%" is really close enough to 1 in 1 for my needs. It just happens that this solution avoids that :)

Answer (score 12):

From what you've said, you could select the number of repeats using pretty much *any* discrete probability distribution that has a mean of `X`.

I would specifically recommend the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)`[*]` with mean `X`, since it models the number of events in any given window, when the events are independently uniformly distributed through a longer time. It therefore has a property of being "scalable"`[**]`: you could divide `X` by 2, run your operation twice as often, and you'd still have essentially the same pattern of events.

If you don't really care about the distribution, you just want the correct rate of events, then at the opposite extreme you could use a totally non-random algorithm. Keep a cumulative "carry value" starting at 0. Then on each iteration add `X` to the carry value, return the integer part and carry forward the fractional part. Of course that makes 8/10 heads impossible.

`[*]` Sadly the name is *not* because it's the distribution of the number of fish that an angler catches in a unit time.

`[**]` Also unrelated to fish.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like OP is describing a [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process).

Comment: A Poisson process... no wonder I couldn't think up a good search term :P

Comment: He's talking about the expected value, not the probability of an event. 'one man's mean is another man's Poisson'

Answer (score 0):

Well... possibly, this is really not a probability.
As long as I can see, you want a possibility to run your task multiple times (0...n) on each function call, keeping randomness in this calls.
The easiest way I can see is to use 2 randomization:

1. Using random() choose, whether run your task or not (lets say, choose random int from 0 to 100, and if it's grater some N - task must be run). Changing those N you'll can adjust your probabilities;
2. If on first step you choose to run your task, run random() again. Lets say, random int from 100 to 500. Lets say it returned number R. Then R%100 will be the number of times you should run your task.

Other case is to simply random() from 0 to 700 (for example) and use random()%100 to define the number of times you should run your task.
If you want to change your 'probabilities' for other values, simply use your own function in place of '%'.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restate the problem just a little bit, to clarify what's going on. In each step, you want to perform the task some number of times. You describe the number of times to perform the task with a probability distribution. Your probability distribution is chosen so that it performs the correct expected number of tasks.

When you describe performing the task 1 time in 10, your distribution is that you have 90% chance of performing the task 0 times and 10% chance of performing it once. This gives an expectation value of one tenth of the number of steps. Generalize this to your "more than 100% of the time" by saying that you want to have the expectation value for the number of times you do the taks equal to, e.g., 1.5 times the number of steps. Select a probability distribution that gives that expectation value, be it half the time you do the task once and half the time twice, or 3/4 of the time you don't do the task and 1/4 of the time you do it 6 times. You'll generally have more than one probability distribution that works.